# How can I calculate the distance from the 3D cursor to a 3D object?

Tags: python, 3d-cursor

I want to determine the distance from the cursor to the surface of the grey object following the y-direction. I tried to do this with *ray_cast*, but this doesn’t give any solutions. How should I handle this problem using Python?

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add a little more information about what you tried with the raycast method and where it failed ?

Comment: @Gorgious I first changed the coordinates of the cursor to the object space of the grey object using matrix_world.inverted. To raycast I tried: greyobject.ray_cast(cursor_in_object_space, (0,1,0)) This gives as a result: (False, Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), -1) Even if I try this ray_cast method with a simple cube I get this as a result.

Comment: Do any of the code in answers work for you with default cube, If not what is your blender version?

Comment: @batFINGER the scene.ray_cast works, but the object.ray_cast not

Comment: To clarify, this is with code from answer, not  a modified version of it, then ... Shrugs, added test run results of simplistic raycast from origin to inside  of default cube and get the  expected  hit in both instances.  If it is modified code that does not work edit it into question.

Answer (score 8):

Since pretty much all raycast Q&As are deprecated because the method takes in the depsgraph and not the view layer since a recent patch and I couldn't find an exact duplicate, here's how to do it :

Make sure to hide any objects between the origin of the ray and the target or else it will fire a false positive.

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# Get evaluated Dependency Graph :
dg = C.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
# Set the ray Begin to the cursor location (in world coords by default)
ray_begin = C.scene.cursor.location
# Set the ray direction
ray_direction = (0, 1, 0)

# By default the ray will be fired with a near infinite length.
# If the script stutters consider adding distance=100 for instance as a parameter
cast = C.scene.ray_cast(dg, ray_begin, ray_direction)

if cast[0]:
    print(f"Hit '{cast[4].name}' at a distance of {cast[1][1]} along Y axis")
```

Result :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

**Closest point on mesh.**

*Ooops on re-reading the question looking for a ray direction, this instead returns the closest point on the mesh to the cursor*

Similarly to [Getting a closest point to 3d cursor gives a wrong result](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197451/getting-a-closest-point-to-3d-cursor-gives-a-wrong-result/197454#197454) each blender object has a closest point on mesh function.

Example code closest point on context object (mesh) to scene cursor.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

scene = context.scene
ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world
mwi = mw.inverted()

hit, loc, n, idx  = ob.closest_point_on_mesh(
        mwi @ scene.cursor.location,
        depsgraph=context.evaluated_depsgraph_get(),
        )
if hit:
    # global distance to hit
    print("HIT distance:", (mw @ loc - scene.cursor.location).length)
```

Test run on default file. .. Cube is

```
HIT distance: 0.9999996423721118
```

from default cursor location.

**Object ray cast.**

Similarly to scene raycast, beautifully  illustrated by [@Gorgeous](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230426/15543), there is `Object.ray_cast` which like closest point on mesh uses local coordinates.

As well as using local coordinates, the object's ray cast method is only interested in itself, and hence forth wont hit any other objects that may be in the path.  (Would need to hide them first)

Script above, same as above, except casting from scene cursor in a direction based on the local coordinate space. (local x direction of context object in this case)

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

local_ray_dir = (1, 1. 1)
scene = context.scene
ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world
mwi = mw.inverted()

hit, loc, n, idx  = ob.ray_cast(
        mwi @ scene.cursor.location,
        local_ray_dir,
        depsgraph=context.evaluated_depsgraph_get(),
        )
if hit:
    # global distance to hit
    print("HIT distance:", (mw @ loc - scene.cursor.location).length)
    # add empty as child at local hit location to test.
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(
        location=loc,
        )
    context.object.parent = ob
```

Result on default file, (1, 1, 1) corner of default cube hit $\sqrt3$ from origin

```
HIT distance: 1.7320499816624955
```

**Shrinkwrap**

Another method to look at would be adding a small mesh and projecting it onto the target via shrinkwrap.

[image]
*Result, some hit some miss given initial location*

Proof of concept script. below, without:, but If a better choice of object, with a vertex group  some verts left out, the y dimension of the modified object will be the distance from object of interest, if any find the target.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
target = context.object

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(
        radius=0.1,
        location=scene.cursor.location
        )
ob = context.object
sw = ob.modifiers.new("Shrinkwrap", 'SHRINKWRAP')
sw.target = target
sw.wrap_method = 'PROJECT'
sw.use_project_y = True
#sw.use_negative_direction = True
sw.use_positive_direction = True
```

Comment: Oh, right it makes sense to use the object ray cast there (no need to worry about obstructing objects) ! I never catched that it's used to test one mesh against rays coming TO it, not FROM it. There is something about matrices that make me want to try any other possible solution which doesn't involve them if possible x)

Comment: Surely you mean nodes, lol.  If and when matrices _"click"_ you never look  back.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer!

Comment: Cheers, given your comment under question, that I also missed, speculate the issue is space related, , is there any rotation on object of interest?

Comment: No the object of interest is not rotated.

Comment: The object.ray_cast still does not hit, while it should when looking at my 3d viewport. Can it be a problem with the way I imported my object? I used bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl and then I did ob = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]